# Does unique_ptr get unallocated when the object containing it gets its destructor called?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have these classes.

Resource.h

```
template<typename T>
class Resource
{
      protected:
              // bunch of member variable
              std::unique_ptr<T> resource;
      public: 
              Resource();
              ~Resource();
 };
```

ResourceManager.h

```
template<typename T>
class ResourceManager
{
    protected:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, Resource<T>> resources;
    public:
        ResourceManager();
        ~ResourceManager()
        {
               resources.clear();
        }
 };
```

`resources.clear()` removes all the elements from the map, and calls the objects' destructors. My question is, do the unique_ptr get unallocated on their own, or if not, do we have to do something to unallocate them?

Comment: Yes.  This is how RAII types work.  It would be pointless to have `unique_ptr` if you still had to manually do something.

Comment: Also see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: destructor in `ResourceManager` is not necessary. map's destructor is called by default which clears it.

Comment: As others already stated, yes. But you should definitely become familiar with [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), as this plays an extremely important role here (and everywhere else in C++, in particular when it comes to exception safety).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does unique_ptr get unallocated when the object containing it gets its destructor called?

In short; Yes.

`resources.clear();` in the destructor is redundant. The `unordered_map` will be cleared automatically when it is destroyed (when `ResourceManager` is destroyed) and this will automatically destroy all the `unique_ptr`s which will in turn deallocate their resources. You don't need to do *anything*.

Answer (score 3):

The unique_ptr member of each `Resource()` instance will be destroyed properly without you adding any extra code.

For this reason too, you do not need to explicitly call `clear()`, as this will happen automatically when the instance of `ResourceManager` is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

There is not point to create an `std::unique_ptr` on the heap (*new std::unique_ptr*).

It acts the same as a simple `int`. It will be removed when it gets out of scope.
With the removing of the `std::unique_ptr` the destructor of the object in the `unique_ptr` will be called

Comment: Nobody is creating `unique_ptr`s on the heap here. What are you talking about?

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's what I'm saying. There is no point. And if it is defined normally it will be destructed when it gets out of scope as well as the object allocated with the `unique_ptr`